# Display selected drop down list item into the specified gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I'm currently working on a project. There is a `GridView` connected to a sql database. There is one of the `DropDown` of ID SumbitTo_dd which is not a column in the database but the items binded to the list are from different table in the database. I want to display the selected item from the list in the last column of the `GridView`, as I have other data also being displayed in the grid. I have mainly 2 questions:

1) How does my display query for the gridview on .aspx file change for Submit To dropdownlist since it is not any column in the db but only its items are which is already handled and binded?

2)How to I display the selected value of the dropdownlist in the specified column of the gridview?

Please Help!

Aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList
  ID="Submit_dd"
  placeholder=""
  Cssclass="form-control"
  runat="server"
></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:GridView
  ID="gridview_TS"
  CssClass="table table-striped table-hover"
  runat="server"
  GridLines="None"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  AllowPaging="True"
  AllowSorting="True"
  PageSize="20"
  DataKeyNames="EmpId_int,ProjectCode_int"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
>
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField
      DataField="Chk_Int"
      HeaderText="Chk_Int"
      SortExpression="Chk_Int"
      Visible="False"
    />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpId_Int" HeaderText="EmpId_Int" />
    . . . .
    <asp:BoundField
      DataField="EmpName_vc"
      HeaderText="Submit To"
      SortExpression="EmpName_vc"
    />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource
  ID="SqlDataSource1"
  runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TSMSConnectionString %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT S.EmpId_Int, T.Chk_Int, T.TSDate_dt, T.ProjectCode_Int, P.ProjectName_vc, 
                     T.CCode_Int, C.CostCode_vc, C.CCode_vc, T.TSRhours_nu, T.TSOhours_nu, T.JobDescp_vc, E.EmpName_vc
                     T.SubmitTo_Int FROM TSHistory T LEFT JOIN Sec_Users S ON T.EmpId_Int= S.EmpId_Int 
                     LEFT JOIN Gen_ProjectList P ON T.ProjectCode_Int = P.ProjectCode_Int 
                     LEFT JOIN Gen_CCList C ON T.CCode_Int= C.CCode_Int LEFT JOIN Gen_Employee E 
                     ON T.EmpId_Int = E.EmpId_Int WHERE (S.UserId_vc = @userId) AND (T.SubmitTo_Int = 0) ORDER BY T.TSDate_dt DESC "
>
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter
      DefaultValue=""
      Name="userId"
      SessionField="user"
      Type="string"
    />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# Bind SubmitTo `DropDownList` from database

```
protected void BindSubmitTo()
{
    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select D.EmpId_Int, E.EmpName_vc from Dept_PM_HOD_List D Left Join Gen_Employee E on D.EmpId_Int = E.EmpId_Int where D.LCode_Int = @intDeptId and D.EmpId_Int<> @intEmpId and(E.EmpType_vc ='PM' or(E.EmpType_vc = 'HOD'))";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intDeptId", LocId.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intEmpId", EmpID.Text);
        cmd.Connection = Cnn;
        // Cnn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader;
        ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
        newItem.Text = "--Select--";
        newItem.Value = "0";
        Submit_dd.Items.Add(newItem);

        Cnn.Open();
        reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = reader["EmpName_vc"].ToString();
            newItem.Value = reader["EmpId_Int"].ToString();
            Submit_dd.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
        reader.Close();
        Cnn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}

//OnCreate_btnClick: Where i want all my enteries to be inserted into the db except of the submitTo_dd value which only for display purpose:


protected void btnCreate_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (DateTxt.Text != "" && (PName_dd.Text != "" || PName_dd.Text != "0") && (CCG_dd.Text != "" || CCG_dd.Text != "0") && (CCL_dd.Text != "" || CCL_dd.Text != "0"))
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTxt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
            if (dt > DateTime.Today)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Invalid date')", true);
                RefreshSrc();
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TSHistory(EmpId_Int, ProjectCode_Int, TSDate_dt, CCode_Int, TSRhours_nu, TSOhours_nu, JobDescp_vc) VALUES(@GEId, @Pcode, @date, @CCode, @Rhr, @Ohr, @job)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GEId", EmpID.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCode", PCode_txt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dt);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCode", CCL_dd.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rhr", R_txt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ohr", O_txt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job", JobDesc_txt.Text);
                //  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp", EmpID.Text);
                cmd.Connection = Cnn;
                Cnn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Cnn.Close();
                displaySubmitTo();
                updateUserDetails();
                // displayTS();
                RefreshSrc();
                RefreshDatabase();
            }
        }
        else if (DateTxt.Text == "")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Select date')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            //validations
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to populate your GridView with the selected value of DropDown? 
PS: Can you show your Table structure?

Comment: Yes i want to display the selected value of my drop down in one of the columns of the grid. Do you want me to post the structure here?

Comment: You have to set `AutoPostBack="true"` for the DropDown and you must provide your DropDown an event of `OnSelectedIndexChanged` whenever the value changed of the DropDown should display in the GridView and insert that value to the GridView through database/directly in that event.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a code sample for directly inserting the selected value to the gridview column?

Comment: Please tell me that, the value you want to insert through `DropDown` is just for display purpose, cause whenever the page loads or you refresh that value will disappear. Is that what you want?

Comment: I dont want the value to disappear. It should stay. The value is from the datasource. I can better explain you through an example:
There are 2 drop down lists:
1)ProjectName 2)Submit To
Project name is a column in the project table and that is where i get the values for the drop downlist and then i display the selected projectname in the  selectcommand query if you see up in the code posted .aspx part. 
Now for Submit To, It is not a column as such in any table but i bind its values by joining tables like EMPLOYEE table and DEPT_PM_HOD table to get the NAMES of employee with some cond.

Comment: so i select the value in the drop down list and want to display this selected item in the respective column of the gridview which is the SubmitTo column. So I'm badly stuck as to how to just get this column in the select command of the grid view and have it to display the selected value on button click for create.

Comment: Mr. @samya, sorry to say but I am not getting fully what you're trying to explain. Can you show your Screenshot, or do you use slack? If yes, then add me into your project channel.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont use slack. But i can send it to you on ur email Id if that is ok? Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: i have sent you an email.